# How to get the first index of a given element in Array/List in Elm?

Tags: arrays, list, elm

In Javascript, one could use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to get the first instance of a given element in an array.

What's the best way to do this in Elm?

```elm
array = Array.fromList ["Stack","Overflow","is","","awesome"]
element = ""

indexOf element array =
  -- should return 3
```

What if we have a list instead of an array?

Comment: Why do you need the index of the element?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Imagine a sliding puzzle game where you can pass the starting position via the query string: http://moroshko.github.io/sliding-puzzle . Query string could looks like: `?start=3,2,1,6,5,4,,8,7`. The model in the game needs to know the location of the empty tile. So, my idea is to split `start` by `,`, then convert it to an array, and then find the position of the empty string. Do you think there is a better way to represent the starting position in the URL? (tiles could have text longer than one char, therefore the commas)

Comment: Sounds sensible. I was just wondering because in functional languages, list/array indices are rarely needed IME.

Comment: I find that it depends more on the problem domain than the programming language. I'm currently writing something that maps a musical note's name to its numeric index, and was surprised to discover no such functionality in either Elm's List or Array modules.

Answer (score 8):

There is a third party module elm-list-extra that provides this function.  "[elemIndex](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/6.1.0/List-Extra#elemIndex)" (works for 0.19).

And this one for < 0.19 [elemIndex](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/circuithub/elm-list-extra/3.7.0/List-Extra#elemIndex)

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, here's a hand-rolled version for List:

```
helper : List a -> a -> Int -> Int
helper lst elem offset = 
  case lst of
    []      -> -1
    x :: xs ->
      if x == elem then offset
      else helper xs elem (offset + 1)

indexOf lst element =
  helper lst element 0
```

`helper` recursively searches the list for the element, keeping track of the number of elements we've visited so far. For the empty list, it returns -1.
If you don't like magic constants, you could easily change the return type to `Maybe Int` and return `Nothing` instead.

And here's a complete program using it (just copy + paste into the online REPL at [elm-lang.org](http://elm-lang.org):

```
import Html exposing (text)

lst = ["Stack","Overflow","is","","awesome"]
element = ""

helper : List a -> a -> Int -> Int
helper lst elem offset = 
  case lst of
    []      -> -1
    x :: xs ->
      if x == elem then offset
      else helper xs elem (offset + 1)

indexOf lst element =
  helper lst element 0

main =
  text (toString (indexOf lst ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another take, composing core library functions. I find this more readable than recursion, and more declarative; it's just a straightforward pipeline of data transformations. The data structure is the last parameter, so that you can partially apply the value that you're looking for, like `idxOfFoo = firstIndexOf "foo"`.

```elm
indicesOf : a -> List a -> List Int
indicesOf thing things =
  things
  |> List.indexedMap (,)
  |> List.filter (\(idx, item) -> item == thing)
  |> List.map fst


firstIndexOf : a -> List a -> Int
firstIndexOf thing things =
  indicesOf thing things
  |> List.minimum
  |> Maybe.withDefault -1


lastIndexOf : a -> List a -> Int
lastIndexOf thing things =
  indicesOf thing things
  |> List.maximum
  |> Maybe.withDefault -1
```

REPL session:

```
> things = ["foo", "bar", "bat", "foo", "baz"]
["foo","bar","bat","foo","baz"] : List String
>
> firstIndexOf "foo" things
0 : Int
>
> lastIndexOf "foo" things
3 : Int
>
```

At a glance, I think this is similar in complexity to CircuitHub's implementation in List.Extra.

Comment: I am getting an error with this:
`Cannot find variable 'fst'

|> List.map fst
`

Answer (score 0):

Code

```
indexOf : a -> Array a -> Int 
indexOf element array =
    let
        item =
            array
                |> Array.toIndexedList                       
                |> List.filter (\tuple -> isElement tuple element)
                |> List.head
                
    in
        case item of 
            Just value ->
                Tuple.first value
            Nothing ->
                -1

isElement : (Int, a) -> a -> Bool
isElement tuple element =    
    Tuple.second tuple == element
```

Usage

```
list =
    [ "a"
    , "b"
    , "c"
    ]        

index =
    list
        |> Array.fromList
        |> indexOf "b"
```